# Wrapped Entity Framework - Unable to create a constant value of type x. Only primitive types are supported in this context

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I want to do an NOT EXISTS query using Entity Framework and have the following query working in LinqPad.

```
var context = new CSSDbEntities();

(from s in context.Appliances
where !context.AvailableResources.Any(es => es.ApplianceId == s.ApplianceId)
select s).Dump();
```

However when I try and transfer this to my application (where I've wrapped my context in a IUnitOfWork interface to allow me to mock it/inject it using Unity/that's how I inherited the code base, it fails with the "Unable to create a constant" exception at runtime.

The actual code I'm trying to execute is...

```
var query = from x in unitOfWork.Appliances
            where !unitOfWork.AvailableResources.Any(es => es.ApplianceId == x.ApplianceId)
            select s;
```

The properties in unitOfWork are implemented as follows...

```
public IDbSet<Appliance> Appliances
{
    get { return _objectContext.Appliances; }
}

public IDbSet<AvailableResource> AvailableResources
{
    get { _objectContext.AvailableResources; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple and I was pointed in the right direction by this related question.

[EF-Code First: Unable to create a constant value of type ''. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584014/ef-code-first-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-only-primitive-type?rq=1)

Instead of using the `unitOfWork` object in my "sub-query" I should have used the association on the Appliance object.

My working query becomes...

```
var query = from x in unitOfWork.Appliances
            where !x.AvailableResources.Any(es => es.ApplianceId == x.ApplianceId)
            select s;
```

Note in the where clause !**x**.AvailableResources.Any instead of !**unitOfWork**.AvailableResources.Any